# Property 'append' does not exist on type 'User'

Tags: angular, typescript

Here I've created 'user.model.ts'

```
export class User {
  
  id: string;
  accountCode: string;
  picture: File;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  companyName: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  password: string;
  parentId: string;
  gmailId:string;
  role: Role;
  customize: Customize;
  account: Account;
  
  constructor() {
    this.role = new Role();
    this.account = new Account();
    this.customize = new Customize();
  }
}
```

This is my 'signup.component.ts'. this file throws an error:

> Property 'append' does not exist on type 'User'

```
let formData = new User();

formData.account = this.user.account;
formData.append('picture', this.signupForm.get('picture').value)
formData.append('firstName', this.signupForm.get('firstName').value)
formData.append('lastName', this.signupForm.get('lastName').value)
formData.append('email', this.signupForm.get('email').value)
formData.append('password', this.signupForm.get('password').value)
formData.append('phone', this.signupForm.get('phone').value)
formData.append('companyName', this.signupForm.get('companyName').value)
formData.parentId = this.user.parentId;
formData.role.id = constants.roleId;
```

Comment: Your `formData` variable contains instance of `User` class. So you can only use public methods and properties of it. In `User` class definition there is no `append` method.

Comment: So what should I do now. I have to send data in FormData format. How can I modify User model accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixed up the `FormData` and `User`.

The `formData` should be `FormData` instance but not `User` instance.

And append the data to `FormData` as below:

```js
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append('account', JSON.stringify(this.user.account));
formData.append('picture', this.signupForm.get('picture').value);
formData.append('firstName', this.signupForm.get('firstName').value);
formData.append('lastName', this.signupForm.get('lastName').value);
formData.append('email', this.signupForm.get('email').value);
formData.append('password', this.signupForm.get('password').value);
formData.append('phone', this.signupForm.get('phone').value);
formData.append('companyName', this.signupForm.get('companyName').value);
formData.append('parentId', this.user.parentId);
formData.append('role', JSON.stringify({ id: constants.roleId }));
```

Comment: Argument of type 'Account' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'. Below line throws this error now.
formData.append('account', this.user.account);

Comment: Revised answer. Sorry about that. You need to convert the object to JSON string via `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Thank you dear!! I.ve tried that which worked for me.